# Why is my API key showing as 'undefined' when I set it up as an environment variable in my Node.js backend server built with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, api-key

API_KEY is showing as 'undefined' when I set it up as an environment variable

My API_KEY is showing as 'undefined' when I set it up as an environment variable. The API call works when I hard code the API Key, so it's not an issue with the key. I can also see that value of it is 'undefined' in the logs. I am trying to access it from a backend server (server.js) built with express. I created a separate .env file in the root of the project's backend directory (at the same level with server.js).

I've installed dot env and included 'import dotenv from dot env' and dotenv.config in my server.js file. I'm including my server.js, .env, and package.json files below.

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = 8000;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.json("Hello World");
});

app.get("/test-cases", async (req, res) => {
  
  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY;
  console.log(API_KEY);
```

.env

```
# Not a real API KEY!!!!!
REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-NgPdmiXotwLWvasdsddsfkFJG4bnvnod3BwRPTsPaeUv
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-genie-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start-backend": "nodemon src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it matters, but try removing the `REACT_APP` prefix from your EV name. That prefix is typically used by Create React App to enable frontend access to environmental variables. Backend EVs normally don't have the prefix. Also, can you try creating a different key/value pair in your `.env`? Something like `FOO=bar`, then run your Express app in debug mode and look at the full contents of `process.env`.

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme) say that when using ES6 imports to just `import 'dotenv/config'`. There's no need for a dedicated `config()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your import statement to:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
```

or try to use require syntax

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
```